# How do servers recognize if it had issued a particular cookie value?

Tags: php, cookies

If i am always using a **random string as cookie value** for "**Keep me logged In**" option to login to my website, then how do servers recognize if it had issued that cookie value.

I mean as Facebook uses a cookie c_user and also a **random string** stored in cookie "**xs**" to login to its website. How does it recognizes if it had issued that **cookie value** of "**xs**" for that account.

Does it always store its cookie value to its database ?

Comment: Probably, yeah. I mean how else? You've answered your own question :p

Comment: The browser sends the cookies back to the server. Depending on what you intend to do with the cookie and what it means the server might not need to store anything.

Comment: The cookie may have a `random value` in it. However, that `random value` will link to a particular user. Change the `random value` it still links to the same user because you update the user with the new `random value`. The cookie is always sent between the server and client.

Comment: So do i always have to store/update the cookie value in the database ? I mean would not it make the whole login process slow ?

Comment: Hmm, I benchmarked this on my 'dual hamster pc'.  The process:  Find user by random hex string. Mark as logged in. Save to the database. It took less than 0.01 of a second. Yes, i can process over 100 database lookups and updates per second. Code I used: [PHP - benchmark database update for autologin](http://pastebin.com/9YvCt3tJ)